# What is the max charger amp rating recommend for charging 4 LiPo 200amp max charge rate batteries in parallel

Tags: charger

What is the max charger amp rating recommend for charging (4) LiPo 12v 200amp max charge rate batteries in parallel. Battery’s are 12v 200ah BMS deep cells with max 200 amp charge rate each. I’m trying to charge as fast as possible but be safe and efficient

Comment: The max rate would be 800A. That is rather a significant amount and the batteries would probably get rather warm. If you want to charge these via a wall socket, that is going to dictate how fast you can charge.

Comment: Parallel devices take 4x the current; series devices need 4x the voltage.

Comment: Great. Thanks very much. It’s great to have a resource with Tech savvy pros. This is a great forum and brain pool. I really appreciate the time and insights…